# listview with 3 buttons android studio kotlin

Tags: android, listview, button, kotlin

Im trying to create a ListView using a Custom Adapter with the following layout:

[ListView Relativelayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v73SP.png)

I just cant manage to make it work, all that i want it to do, is that when clicking in map button, it sets visibility of my "viewlist" layout to gone. and sets visibility of "map" layout to visible and load an url.

same goes for the website button

and when pressing the phone botton i need it to perform the makecall("number")

This is what i have so far:

ListViewLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="372dp"
        android:layout_height="153dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.023">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtvlista1"
            android:layout_width="337dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:text="Name: Here goes the contact name"
            tools:text="Name: Here goes the contact name" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mapalv"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtvlista1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
            android:background="@drawable/website" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mapalv3"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtvlista1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/phone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mapalv2"
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtvlista1"
            android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mapa" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Negocios data class:

```
data class Negocios(var name: String, var button: Button)
```

Custom Adapter:

```
    class CustomAdapter(var context: Context, var negocios: ArrayList<Negocios>): BaseAdapter() {

private class ViewHolder(row: View?) {
    var txtNombres: TextView
    var mapbutton: Button
    var phonebutton: Button
    var websitebutton: Button



    init {
        this.txtNombres = row?.findViewById(R.id.txtvlista1) as TextView
        this.mapbutton = row?.findViewById(R.id.buttonmap) as Button
        this.phonebutton = row?.findViewById(R.id.buttonmap) as Button
        this.websitebutton = row?.findViewById(R.id.buttonmap) as Button


    }
}

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

    var view: View?
    var viewHolder: ViewHolder
    if (convertView == null) {
        var layout = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        view = layout.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false)
        viewHolder = ViewHolder(view)
        view.tag = viewHolder
    }else {
        view = convertView
        viewHolder = view.tag as ViewHolder
    }

    var negocios: Negocios = getItem(position) as Negocios
    viewHolder.txtNombres.text =negocios.name
    viewHolder.mapbutton.setOnClickListener {
        seleccion.visibility = View.GONE
        mapa.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    }
    viewHolder.phonebutton.setOnClickListener {
        makeCall("phone number")
    }
    viewHolder.websitebutton.setOnClickListener {
        seleccion.visibility = View.GONE
        website.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }


    return view as View


}

override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
    return negocios.get(position) 
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return negocios.count() 
}
```

Menu for search:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android2="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item
        android2:id="@+id/menuSearch"
        android2:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android2:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass = "android.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

NegociosActivity:

```
class NegociosActivity: AppCompatActivity (){

internal lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<String>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var lista = findViewById(R.id.lista) as ListView


    var arrNegocios: ArrayList<Negocios> = ArrayList()
    arrNegocios.add(Negocios("AAAAAAAAAA", R.id.buttonmap))
    arrNegocios.add(Negocios("BBBBBBBBB", R.id.buttonpho))
    arrNegocios.add(Negocios("CCCCCCCCC", R.id.buttonweb))


    lista.adapter = CustomAdapter(applicationContext, arrNegocios)



}
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    val inflater = menuInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu)
    val item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch)
    val searchView = item.actionView as SearchView

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
            adapter.filter.filter(newText)

            return false
        }
    })


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

thank you in advance 4 ur support

Regards

Comment: where's the code you've done?

Comment: Please show as what you have designed so far, so we can help you finish what you've started with.

Comment: code added, tyvm